# Site not coming up in Google search?

Tags: google-search

I've read the questions and searched. 
My URL is: 
http://straightroaddentalpratice.com

I recently created a website for one of our client, and added content and images are setup. I've verified the site with google webmasters, added analytics to the site.
Also submitted XML sitemap in google webmasters.

The issue that I am experiencing is that I am searching for the keyword "straight road dental practice" and our domain "http://straightroaddentalpratice.com" is not showing up at all. Even if I type as "straightroaddentalpratice" the domain doesn't show up.

But when I search for the "site:straightroaddentalpractice.com" all my pages appear to be indexed and available.

Although other directories listing, google+ page appears for the search.

I would appreciate if some one could assist me, if am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that URL just has an incredibly low PageRank. A couple of choice searches:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22straightroaddentalpractice%22 - returns a couple of results at the bottom of the page.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22straight%20road%20dental%20practice%22#filter=0&q=%22straight+road+dental+practice%22&start=50 - shows some results on the 6th page for me.

The site has been properly indexed, but just isn't recognised as a "good" result.

Actually fixing it is a more in-depth SEO issue, which I'm not really qualified to help with :)

Answer (score 1):

Super old question but here is a new answer.  Your domains authority was too low and your business was too new (at the time). People often think that because you can purchase things on the internet instantaneously, that your site should rank instantaneously as well. Sadly this is not the case. Your business and website need to build trust on the internet. This can be achieved through local citations, backlinks (good ones) and good ole fashioned waiting.